# How can I copy a directory tree but exclude .svn directories?

Tags: svn

Here is the problem:

Loop through all files and subfolders copying all contents EXCEPT .svn into another location.

I can think of some pretty hairy ways to do this but am wondering if anyone knows a real simple function to save me a bit of time? Thanks.

Comment: Out of interest, and having seen the answer. I am being stupid but what is the reason for taking this out of subversion control.  this is a genuine foolhardy question!!

Comment: I did a similar thing to back up a local copy of a repository at work because it was quite large to checkout each time, saving lots of time. It was just a 'learning/breaking' copy that wasn't going to be checked back in - otherwise i wouldn't recommend this.

Comment: You should modify the question to more clearly state that you're using AutoIt, or remove that tag if you don't require an AutoIt solution.

Comment: @brumScouse — generally you want to export things from version control when publishing them.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the [`svn export`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re10.html) command.  It will populate a target folder with the content of a working copy (or a revision on a repository).

Comment: Just an advisory. The OP wants to copy _all contents_, which might include files not under version control. The documentation clearly states that `svn export` will NOT COPY _files not under version control_.

Comment: @msx yes it might have, according to the literal question text.  Luckily the actual problem, which lies underneath the words and the phrasing, was about the version contolled content

Comment: @xtofl Obviously. I perfectly agree with you. Accepting your answer as the best indicates that the OP is completely satisfied with the solution. I myself was searching for a solution to copy everything but `.svn` folder and `svn export` does not solve my problem. Hence, my comment ... hopefully it will spare time to others searching for the solution to a problem similar to mine.

Answer (score 5):

<del>Use rsync and the `--exclude` switch.</del>

… although in this specific case, the better option is [svn export](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re10.html)

Answer (score 4):

We sometimes uses Beyond Compare (http://beyond-compare.softonic.com/): select the root source directory and the destination one, exclude .svn and do a synchronization. This is useful if you need to do it again: saves the settings as a project.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, svn export.

However, you could also do this easily using Xcopy and the exclude switch, see here:

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true

and here: http://commandwindows.com/xcopy.htm

The second link has a much better description of the exclude switch.

Answer (score 1):

So my quick and dirty way of doing this recently was using python:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(inRootDirArg):
        for d in dirs: 
            if d.startswith('.'):#excludes directories that start with '.'
                continue
            ...<logic to move your desired directories>...
```

This solution disregards any directory starting with a '.', but if i needed to be more specific it isn't difficult to modify it to omit just .svn directories.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TortoiseSVN, use Export ...

Answer (score 0):

Use Cmd

```
Dir/a-d/s/b >>1.txt
```

and Use AutoIt to read the file,better use _FileReadToArray,and the in a loop,check the file path if it has an '.svn'in it

Answer (score 0):

If autoit isn't needed, you can use xcopy with an exclusion file:

```
xcopy "..\source\" "..\destination\" /E /Y /R /exclude:exclude.txt
```

exclude.txt should contain:

```
\.svn\
```